# Incorporating Siddhi Query Runtime in a Multithreading Environment

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

Hi: I have an environment that subscribes remotely to an Event Channel. The Event channel will push the events to my environment, and I will have many rules to process the events. I am planning to use Siddhi framework to implement these rules and process the events accordingly.

After I went over the Siddhi codebase, it seems that the Siddhi execution pattern is well represented in the siddhi samples, for example, https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-samples/performance-samples/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/performance/SimpleFilterMultipleQueryPerformance.java. It performs the following step:

(1) create a Siddhi Runtime with Stream Queries (query 1, query 2..) specified;
(2) create input handler for the input stream.
(3) construct events and then sends the events using the input handler;
(4) The created Siddhi Runtime is added with callback, and when the output stream produces some output events, the callback function is called with output events passed in.

With simple code instrumentation, I found that the thread that sends the event via the input handler, is the same thread that handles the callback function. That makes me infer that the whole Siddhi runtime is running in a single thread, synchronously. Is this statement correct?

From the Siddhi Example code that I mentioned above, the code uses multiple event publisher threads to handle the sending of the events.  So it seems to me that by using the multiple event sending threads, we can achieve the multithreading execution of the Siddhi runtime.

Since I will have many Siddhi queries to be defined, query1, query 2, ... etc,  There are two options:

(option 1)similar to that example code in the Siddhi code base, "SimpleFilterMultipleQueryPerformance.java",  I create one siddhi runtime object, then I register all of the Siddhi queries to this single runtime. Then I use multiple threads to send events to the input handlers of this single runtime, concurrently.

(option 2) I created multiple Siddhi runtime objects, to each object I register a subset of the Siddhi queries.  I control my threads, so that one particular thread is to send events only dedicated to the input handlers corresponding to one particular runtime object. that is, one thread to send events to a dedicated Siddhi runtime object; Each runtime is guaranteed  to be invoked by only one thread.

I like to know which option is better, in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

Your inquiry is around using Siddhi as a library[1]. And your understanding of the message flow is correct for a scenario where you use Siddhi as a library. But with Siddhi 4.x.x ability is there to work with transports directly through sources and sinks. Refer [2] for more information regarding this. Also Stream Processor [3] which is the product encapsulating adds more features such as an IDE with running, debugging capability. Quick start guide[4] will be a good starting point.

> That makes me infer that the whole Siddhi runtime is running in a single thread, synchronously.

Yes same thread which calls inputHandler.send() will traverse through the complete event flow till callbacks so this is synchronous behavior but note that send() does not return anything and also there is no guarantee that every event reached callback(Some can get filtered out). Also there is a async mode which you can enable using annotations. In that mode We use disruptors[5] to make message flow async. Multiple parallel threads can exist which does execute the same path, but carrying a different event forward. Siddhi is designed to be multi threaded in that way. So multiple parallel event execution is possible. If you invoke same inputHandler using multiple threads those events will be processed in-parallel.

Regarding your options, If your queries are mutually-exclusive, creating more Siddhi App Runtimes and running them in-parallel(option 2) will be more performant as there is less contention. It is equivalent to vertical scaling. However if queries are connected to each other meaning you have to connect one callback to another input handler, performance will degrade in option 2. In such cases option 1 will work fine. Just for your knowledge We do have a distributed deployment[6] also to handle high event rate scenarios.

[1] [https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Using+Siddhi+as+a+Library][1]

[2] https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-architecture/

[3] https://wso2.com/analytics/features

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP410/Quick+Start+Guide

[5]https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/

[6]https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP420/Fully+Distributed+Deployment

Thanks,

Tishan

Answer (score 0):

Siddhi now supports configurable threading[1] from Siddhi version 4.1.50. This enables you to configure a number of worker threads to process events in parallel.

[1]https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#threading-and-asynchronous